How do I add a CRF layer to a BERT model for NER tasks?
I have created an NER model using BERT to detect medical entities which works great. I'm trying to add a CRF layer on top of my BERT model to enhance its performances but I'm getting an error that I can't seem to resolve.
Here's the error :
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-99c3c401704b> in <cell line: 85>()
     83 
     84 # Start training
---> 85 trainer.train()

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torchcrf/__init__.py in _validate(self, emissions, tags, mask)
    165             no_empty_seq_bf = self.batch_first and mask[:, 0].all()
    166             if not no_empty_seq and not no_empty_seq_bf:
--> 167                 raise ValueError('mask of the first timestep must all be on')
    168 
    169     def _compute_score(

ValueError: mask of the first timestep must all be on

as for my code, here it is :
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from torchcrf import CRF
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import DataCollatorForTokenClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, BertTokenizerFast

def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):

    tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(examples["tokens"], truncation=True, is_split_into_words=True)

    labels = []
    for i, label in enumerate(examples[f"ner_tags"]):

        word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)
        previous_word_idx = None
        label_ids = []
        for word_idx in word_ids:
            # Special tokens have a word id that is None. We set the label to -100 so they are automatically
            # ignored in the loss function
            if word_idx is None:
                label_ids.append(-100)
            # We set the label for the first token of each word.
            elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx])
            # For the other tokens in a word, we set the label to either the current label or -100, depending on
            # the label_all_tokens flag.
            else:
                label_ids.append(label[word_idx] if label_all_tokens else -100)
            previous_word_idx = word_idx

        labels.append(label_ids)

    tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
    return tokenized_inputs



label_all_tokens = False

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
tokenized_data = my_dataset_dict.map(tokenize_and_align_labels, batched=True)
data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer=tokenizer)

class BERT_CRF_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, bert_model, num_labels):
        super(BERT_CRF_Model, self).__init__()
        self.bert = bert_model
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(self.bert.config.hidden_size, num_labels)
        self.crf = CRF(num_labels, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, labels=None):
        outputs = self.bert(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        sequence_output = self.dropout(outputs[0])  # Last hidden state
        emissions = self.classifier(sequence_output)

        if labels is not None:
            # CRF loss
            loss = -self.crf(emissions, labels, mask=attention_mask.bool(), reduction='mean')
            return loss
        else:
            # CRF decoding (prediction)
            prediction = self.crf.decode(emissions, mask=attention_mask.bool())
            return emissions  # Make sure to return emissions here


class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
    def __init__(self, *args, crf_layer=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.crf_layer = crf_layer

    def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
        labels = inputs.pop("labels")  # Extraire les labels
        emissions = model(**inputs)  # Obtenir les émissions du modèle
        
        emissions = torch.stack(emissions) if isinstance(emissions, list) else emissions 

        # Vérifiez le masque d'attention
        mask = inputs["attention_mask"].bool()
        if mask.size(0) == 0 or mask[:, 0].sum() == 0:
            raise ValueError("Le masque du premier pas de temps doit être activé")

        # Calculer la perte CRF
        loss = -self.crf_layer(emissions, labels, mask=mask)

        return (loss, inputs) if return_outputs else loss




# Load BERT model
from transformers import BertModel

bert_model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = BERT_CRF_Model(bert_model, num_labels=len(unique_labels))


crf_layer = CRF(num_tags=len(unique_labels))


training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="my_awesome_ner_model",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=12,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=12,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    push_to_hub=True,
)


trainer = CustomTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_data["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_data["val"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    crf_layer=crf_layer  # Pass the CRF layer
)


trainer.train()

I'm not sure exactly why exactly I'm getting this error, any help would be appreciated !

pytorch-crf, expects all first tokens to be unmasked, does not accept -100 as a padding token id (only id's that are in [0, num_labels-1]), it expects Torch tensors and it of course expects the tensors to be on the same device. So, do something as follows:
            mask = labels != self.pad_token_id
            mask[:, 0] = True

            emissions_torch = torch.from_numpy(logits).float().to(self.device)
            mask_torch = torch.from_numpy(mask).bool().to(self.device)

            predictions = self.model.crf.decode(emissions=emissions_torch, mask=mask_torch)

Good luck.
